# Power Query: Duplicate row moved to column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have data where the invoice column is duplicated and results in multiple rows, I need to move the 2nd, 3rd etc instance of the code column to a new column and having trouble doing this in power query.

| Invoice | Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 988532 | 57902 | 65 |
| 988532 | 57963 | 70 |

Goal result

| Invoice | Code | Code2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 988532 | 57902 | 57963 | 135 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below in powerquery It groups, takes the total, and combines the Codes, then later splits the codes into columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Invoice", type text}, {"Code", type text}, {"Amount", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Invoice"}, {
    {"Sum", each List.Sum([Amount]), type number},
    {"combined", each Text.Combine([Code],","), type text}
}),
ColHeaders=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[combined], each List.Count(Text.Split(_,","))))}, each "Code"& Text.From(_)),
split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "combined", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), ColHeaders)
in split
```

[image]